# I set PATH variable of CATALINA_HOME, but when I try to create new FIle in java it goes wrong

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu, catalina

Firstly, I set PATH variable `CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat` then I check it in terminal `cd $CATALINA_HOME` it's works.
Secondly, I created `file.properties` and wrote `catalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%`.
Lastly, I tried to run following code

```
@Autowired Enviroment enviroment;
String path = environment.getProperty("catalina.home") + File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator + "templates" + File.separator;
File dir = new File(path);
```

but that doesn't work

```
 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/templates does not exist.
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:124)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.(FileTemplateLoader.java:121)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.(FileTemplateLoader.java:107)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(Configuration.java:439)
```

Comment: what is `file.properties`, why do you think every property of this file will be set as system property ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi, I do not I have not worked with this type of file, in error message we see `%CATALINA_HOME%/` does it mean what was not recognize that strig?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the environment variable `CATALINA_HOME` in Java, use `System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME")`.

I'm not sure what gives you the idea that a `.properties` file will make any use of environment variable values.  It does not do this at all. If you have set `catalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%` in your properties file, then the value you get back from the property `catalina.home` will always be the string `%CATALINA_HOME%`.  Also, the `File` class will pay no attention at all to environment variable values.  In your case, `%CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/templates` does not exist because there is (almost certainly) no subdirectory in Tomcat's current working directory with the name `%CATALINA_HOME%`.